# Google Analytics API different values for same day with different date ranges

Tags: google-analytics

I am using a R API to access to access Google Analytics. I am trying to retrieve number of page views for a given day (2014-09-04).

I extract data from 2014-09-04 to 2014-09-10:

```
ga$getData(id, start.date="2014-09-01", end.date="2014-09-10", metrics = "ga:pageviews",filters = "ga:pagePath=~operating_system")
```

I got 1170 page views for 2014-09-04

Now when I extract data from 2014-09-01 to 2014-09-30:

```
ga$getData(id, start.date="2014-09-01", end.date="2014-09-30", metrics = "ga:pageviews",filters = "ga:pagePath=~operating_system")
```

I got 1115 page views for 2014-09-04

I dont understand why those two numbers are different.

Comment: How do you know the dates are different? Are you using a `ga:date` dimension not listed in your code samples?

Comment: Because it already returns me a dataframe with a split by date

Comment: How is that happening if you're not using a `ga:date` dimension? I feel like there's a piece missing here.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly, but my guess is that there are date-time boundary differences between what Google sends you and how R quantizes the data when it splits by date.

Answer (score 0):

That's caused by the data sampling of GA. The [unsampled reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2601061) only in Analytics 360.

For more information on data sampling, you can read [this answer](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192).